# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

When I execute this script to create 2 tables, where the STORE column in the CUSTOMER table references the ID column in the USERS table (both columns are INT):

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `part_finder` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `part_finder`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder`.`users` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Account organisation user belongs to',
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `passenc` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(55) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` DECIMAL(1,0) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_reg` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_visit` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtreg` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtvisit` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `visits` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pass` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `make_filter_on` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  `brand_filter_on` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `part_finder`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder`.`customer` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address_2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `state` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `zip` CHAR(5) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `website` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(55) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_customer_users_idx` (`store` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`store`)
    REFERENCES `part_finder`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `part_finder`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder`.`customer` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address_2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `state` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `zip` CHAR(5) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `website` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(55) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_customer_users_idx` (`store` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`store`)
    REFERENCES `part_finder`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I'm using InnoDB, I've checked the data types of my foreign key columns and I've made sure I'm using a primary key in the referenced table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the columns in the parent tables are `INT UNSIGNED`?

They need to be exactly the same data type in both tables.

[**Foreign Key Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

**Reasons that you may get foreign key constraint error:**

2. You are trying to reference a nonexistent key on the target table.
   Make sure that it is a key on the other table (it can be a `primary or unique key`),
3. The types of the columns are not the same (exception is the column
   on the referecing table can be `nullable`).

Answer (score 0):

Column definitions must match in both parent and child tables.

**Parent**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder`.`users` (

  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- <----- this is unsigned

  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

**Child**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_finder`.`customer` (
...

`store` INT(10) NOT NULL, -- <----------- this is signed

...
  INDEX `fk_customer_users_idx` (`store` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`store`)
    REFERENCES `part_finder`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

**Change**:

```
`store` INT(10) NOT NULL, -- <----------- this is signed
```

**To**:

```
`store` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- <---- now this too is unsigned
```

**Refer to**: [**MySQL: Foregin Key Constaints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)